# "blank page" after each chapter with a strange symbol on it, how can I get rid of it?

Tags: latex, nonblank

I use Latex, document class is book. After each chapter, there is a page with page head and foot, and also a strange symbol on it, and the rest is blank. Then after this page a normal blank page is generated. Has anyone ever encountered such problem? How can I get rid of this "non-blank" blank page?
Thank you very much and best wishes!

Comment: Try asking on http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem, and found that it depended on the mix of packages I had, and the order in which initialisation commands were made. I enclose my normal header. The only non-standard part is partpg which does for chapters what chappg does for chapters.

```
\documentclass[10pt,notitlepage]{book}%
\usepackage[a4paper,twoside,bindingoffset=0in,left=1.25in,right=1.25in,top=1in,
            b   ottom=1.5in,includemp,marginparwidth=1.25in,heightrounded,verbose]{geometry} 
\usepackage{sectsty} % Fancy section Headers.
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Headers and footers.
\usepackage{parskip} % Paragraph layout - no indent, line space between.
\usepackage{tocbibind} % Include index, toc, and biblio in toc.
\usepackage[auto]{partpg} % Modified version of chappg to provide part-pageno type page numbering.
\usepackage{appendix} % Multiple appendix sections in multi part document.
\usepackage[style=altlist,toc=true]{glossary} % Enhanced glossary commands.
\usepackage{calc} % Provide inline calculation of variable setting.
\usepackage{color} % Colour support.
\usepackage{xifthen} % Programming commands.
\usepackage{longtable}
\input{dataTypeDef}
%----------------------------------------------------------
\fontsize{10}{12}
\partfont{\raggedright}
\settocname{Table of Contents}
\makeglossary
% There is a conflict between partpg and makeglos.
% To generate the glossary, run makeglos AFTER removing the next line.
\renewcommand{\partpgsep}{.}
\renewcommand{\glossaryname}{Glossary}
\setlength{\headheight}{13.6pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}%
{% Ensure appendices in different parts restart numbering at A each time 
\renewcommand{\restoreapp}{} 

\fancypagestyle{plain}{% Redefine style to use the relevant elements on the part pages
\fancyhfoffset[LE,RO]{\marginparsep+\marginparwidth}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.1pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.1pt}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}}%

\makeatletter% Redefine cleardoublepage so blank pages at the end of chapters have desired header.
\def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else
  \hbox{}
  \vspace*{\fill}
  \pagestyle{plain}
  \newpage
  \if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}
\makeatother

\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your chapter files are ANSI-encoded instead of Unicode. I have recent personal experience with Unicode files generating weird symbols that disappear after I convert them to ANSI.